# Show / Hide field - mobx-form

Tags: reactjs, mobx

I'm looking to show / hide a form field based on the value of another field

I can observe the event via observers

```
rules: "required|string|between:1,100",
      observers: [
        {
          key: "value", // can be any prop
          call: ({ form, field }) => {

            //value is X hide the other field
            form.$("other-field") // ... hide this


}

....
```

Do I need to set some external state to do this or is there a way via mobx-form?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the field type to be a hidden field

```
form.$("other-field").set("type", "hidden");
```